# Tailwind CSS utility class using a breakpoint is being overridden

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to add a different margin for large screens, and my breakpoints are not working. They work elsewhere except in this specific component.

My React.js component:

```js
<Link to={`/dashboard/files/${name}`} className="hover:text-black">
  <div className="bg-white h-24 w-28 rounded-2xl m-2 sm:m-4 inline-block p-1.5 cursor-pointer hover:shadow-md">
  <div className="h-16 w-20 m-auto"> {icon} </div>
    <Para content={name} />
  </div>
</Link>
```

The `m-4` class is being overridden by a value in `_spacing.scss`. I don't know what that file is or where it comes from. It's overriding the `m-2` class with `!important`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried overriding the value from the external SCSS file by adding your own "important" modifier? The exclamation point should be placed after the breakpoint variant value. For example:

```js
<div className="sm:!m-4 ..." />
```

See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier

If you run into a lot of problems with SCSS overrides and want to ensure that your Tailwind utility classes always apply, you could instead add the `important` option to your `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  important: true,
}
```